# How in SQL (Redshift) to select with IF condition?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a 5 columns table. Column1 which has values 'A', 'B', 'C' and 'D' and another column2 having int values from 0 to 20, and column3, column4 and column5 have other values, not important for now.

I want to select all records in the table, but not records having in column1 value 'B'. However, records which have in colum1 value 'B', should meet the condition having in column2 a value > 10. If they have in column2 for ex. 15, we can include them in the select.

How to select this?

```
SELECT 
column1
, column2
, column3
, column4
, column5 

FROM tableA

WHERE 
only_include_values_B_from_column1_IF_it_has_in_column2_value_superior_than_10
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Your explanation is quite confusing.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want `OR`:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4, column5 
FROM tableA a
WHERE column1 <> 'B' OR column2 > 10
```